# Excel: better ways to express this as a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

X is an integer > 0

For x = 0, return 0; for all other x, return 1

Solutions I have considered:

1. `IF (whatever)`, obviously. Want to avoid it if possible, just because nested/lengthy formulas using them get messy.
2. `IFERROR (x/x, 0)`

Hey TBH I remembered the existence of `IFERROR ()` just as I was writing this. That is probably the solution I'll use if no one posts anything better.

Just curious at this point.

Comment: -1 excluding IF(...) as a solution for a requirement stated as if x ... then ... else ... is just ridiculous

Comment: You state that x is an integer > 0, so why would you need to test if it is zero?

Answer (score 4):

=MIN(A1,1) seems self-documenting

Answer (score 2):

How about the ordinary ternary IF clause:

```
IF(x = 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I said no If()! ;) I wanted something shorter and cleaner just for readability's sake. I already have loads of functions in this sheet that are like If(foo,If(foo2,If(foo3...),...,...)" and I am trying to improve on that.Originally I was going to just use "x/x" and deal with the #Errors, but IFERROR seems like it can add a level of not-too-verbose polish to that which is why I said I'd most likely use that.

Comment: Yes and sorry if my shorthand wasn't clear but the ternary was what I meant by "If(whatever)".  There doesn't really appear to be an "If(whatever)"!  I think "If(whatever,,)" is the simplest valid construction.  But to be hyper-specific, when I originally wrote "whatever", what I *actually* meant was "logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false]" ;)

Comment: Well, you do want something piecewise, which you cannot construct out of analytic expressions like x/x alone: continuous functions of continuous functions are continuous. What's the problem with having an IF? Maybe a a MAX will do?

Comment: `IF()` seems like the correct choice from a semantic point of view. Aren't you just trying to be clever for clever's sake otherwise?

Comment: Unless we are misunderstanding what it is you are looking for, from your question it appears you want one value if the value of 'X' is true and another if 'X' is false.  This meets that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
=NOT(X=0)+0
```

where **X** can either be:

1. a reference to another cell
2. a number
3. a name referring to a cell or value
4. a formula

**Example:**
[image]

When you remove the "+0" you'll get either TRUE or FALSE.